# Can't Set ComboBox.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have the following code:

```
var db = new db();
var temp =
    db.Table.Where(a => 
        a.id == 1);

if(temp.Any()) {
    var listItem = temp.Select(a => new listItem(a)).Single();
    comboBox.SelectedItem = listItem;
}
```

It runs to the line: comboBox.SelectedItem = listItem; and listItem does contain a value, but right after the line runs, comboBox.SelectedItem is still equal to null. I don't see how this is possible since listItem has a value, what could possibly be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `ListItem` that does not exist in the `CobmoBox`'s items.

Comment: So I have to populate my list box first, let me see if the ordering of my code is causing this as you say

Comment: If I'm understanding your post correctly, I am not having that problem.  The combo box has been populated with the item I'm trying to set it's selectedItem to.

Comment: I see a call to a constructor here:
`var listItem = temp.Select(a => new listItem(a)).Single();`